# How to prevent IE from whole-page-zooming when someone "pinches" on touch screen?

Tags: javascript, touch, internet-explorer-11, multi-touch

I have an element with a line graph in it that I want to be able to handle pinch zooms, so the user can zoom in or out on a certain part of the graph.  This works great in every browser except IE11, where instead of zooming the element, it zooms the entire page.

Is there an obvious way to prevent this kind of functionality, so IE allows for pinch-zooming on specific elements?  Or maybe there's some way to capture the pinch event, e.preventDefault(), and maybe zoom the graph manually?

I have asked a few other people to try to reproduce the issue, and it seems like it's not a problem on Windows 10... I'm on Windows 7.  Could this really be platform dependent?  But even if it is, maybe intercepting the events is a good approach?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Here's an example of a chart where I am having this problem:
http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/FlexChartZoom/FlexChartZoom/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [official documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/hh772726(v=vs.85).aspx), programmatic control of touch and gesture recognition requires Windows 8 or later.

Comment: Interesting fact about the link: the official documentation points to an MSDN article that directly forwards to mozilla.org :-)